# Facebook app deep linking has stopped working as it used to

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking

Has anything changed with the FB app and deep linking?

Fore example, using the following link `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=[Query]` format, used to open the FB app **directly to the search section of Pages**.

This is not true anymore. The app opens, but the previous link now leads to its Main Page.

Is there an alternative format that is currently functional?